# contract accept header with api resource and feign client

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

feign client works with contracts but not actual api resource

I have a feign client with integration tests against a contract. everything works fine but when moving to end-to-end tests, the feign client keeps getting 406 status code. How could it happen?

Api resource (very standard API in controller):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class DateController {
 @GetMapping(path = "/somepath", produces = "text/plain")
 public ResponseEntity<String> getDateAsString(){   
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("20190909");
}
```

Contract:

```
 request {
        method GET()

        urlPath ($(consumer('/somepath'),
                producer('/somepath'))) {
        }
# is below normal based on the controller API definition?
        headers {accept(textPlain())}
    }

    response {
        status 200
        headers {contentType(textPlain())}
        body("20190909")
    }
```

feign client (should "produces = ..." in the feign client?):

```
public interface DateClient {
@GetMapping(path = "/somepath", produces = "text/plain")
String getDateAsString();
}
```

here is the feign client integration test

```
public class DateClientTest {
    @Autowired
    private DateClient dateClient;

    @Test
    public void getDate() throws Exception {
        String date = dateClient.getDateAsString();
        assertThat(date).isEqualTo("20190909");
    }
```

Since feign client works fine with the contract, I expect the same behavior with actual API resource. unfortunately, in real environment, I got 406 status code from dependent micro service.

Can anyone help if there is anything wrong with the contract or feign client?

As an experiment, I removed "produces = ..." in feign client as below (should this be correct feign client?). Now the actual environment works fine but this fails with the contract.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/somepath")
String getDateAsString();
```

here version info:

```
springboot version: 1.5.3.RELEASE
spring cloud version: Dalston.RELEASE
spring-cloud-contract version: 1.2.1.RELEASE
```

this is a simple Get request if using curl command to my microservice:

```
curl -v "http://localhost:8090/somepath"
```

and below is the error logging from feign client:

```
message="Feign client received an unsuccessful response.", status="406", reason="Not Acceptable"
path="/somepath"
```

there is no consumer (I omitted one query parameter "?id={id}"

Comment: Can you provide more details? A sample maybe? Which version of contract are you using? Which version of Boot? How does your controller look like, what is the exact request that you're sending and why do you get 406 ? I don't see `consumes` on your controller so no wonder that you get 406.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak - added version info; controller just as api resource code; the question is how feign client works fine with the contract but not with the actual api resource

Comment: ```
springboot version: 1.5.3.RELEASE
spring cloud version: Dalston.RELEASE
spring-cloud-contract version: 1.2.1.RELEASE``` these versions are ancient. Please upgrade to the latest ones

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak - sorry the microservice involves too much changes if upgrading to latest versions; could you please quick review if there is anything abnormal? I would like to get opinions from experts like you.

Comment: Nothing that looks suspicious. I haven't seen your base class though

Comment: should feign client have "produces =..." since it's a client; also in contract request block, should "headers {accept(textPlain())}" be there? I suspect these are causing issues; I also updated the controller but keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Can you show your base class please

Comment: the controller updated in API resource section; is this the base class you are referring? or the feign client test class? in  my case, my application is the contract consumer;

Comment: I'm referring to the base class for test. I still didn't get your plugin setup. I don't have much information on this issue.

Comment: I will create a simple provider and consumer posting  in GitHub. I would think this is a spring contract bug